# How to sort Search Results based on a Field Value in Lucene-3.0.2?

Tags: sorting, lucene

I have googled a lot and also searched in stackoverflow.com about **how to sort search results based on a Field Value in Lucene 3.0.2**, but not found any useful data. I'm getting the search results from the index, based on the user query but not able to sort the results based on field like **id** or **date**.

I have pasted my code here for searching lucene index- http://pastie.org/1033974.

Please help me to solve this problem. If you provide me some example code or links where i can find that will be better.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [IndexSearcher](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html) class has a couple of [search methods](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search(org.apache.lucene.search.Weight,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Filter,%20int,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Sort)) that takes a [Sort](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html) Object that you have to use. A Sort object is basically a wrapper around one or more [SortField](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/SortField.html) objects which hold details on what field to sort on and how.

Note that a field must be indexed to be used for sorting.